# Error on build Spring gradle project generated from Spring Initializr

Tags: java, spring, gradle, intellij-idea

I've created a demo Gradle project called `test-jdbc-demo` from [Spring](https://start.spring.io/) using some dependencies and change nothing, just unziped and imported on Intellij using Open -> build.gradle file and tried too using `Import` from default Intellij window. When imported the project is not build and a error about gradle dependencies occurs. I'm using Intellij 2019.3, JDK 1.8 on Ubuntu.

**Error**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/augusto.cadini/projects/Spring Applications/test-jdbc-demo/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.2.4.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.2.4.RELEASE')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 208ms
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.jdbc'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Does it build from the command line? `./gradlew clean build`

Answer (score 0):

This drove me crazy.  I was getting the same errors (this is from a clean project generated from Spring Initializr).  Turned out it was an issue with the Gradle version. When I ran a build from the command line, I got the following error message

[image]

Once I updated gradle it build with no issues.

Comment: how to change version gradle in spring-init or in project?

Comment: you can have multiple versions of gradle installed side by side.  For me, I just made sure that the 'gradle' command was mapped to the latest version in the environment setttings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was due to incompatible versions of Spring Boot and JDK.
Initially while creating the project from Spring Initializer I tried using Spring Boot 3.0.6 version for JDK 11 which was incompatible.
After changing the Spring Boot version to 2.7.11 for JDK 11 the error got resolved.